# Printing out actual error message for ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

How can I actually print out the ValueError's message after I catch it?

If I type `except ValueError, err:` into my code instead of `except ValueError as err:`, I get the error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
try:
    ...
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3 you have to cast to string explicitly: `print(str(e))`.

Comment: It's not true that you have to cast to string explicitly in Python 3. At least as of 3.5.

Comment: Note that in Python 3 you have to cast to string explicitly: print(str(e)), at least for Python 3.6.6

Comment: @Bengt I think you should post it as an answer. Python 3.7.5  requires the cast

Comment: I concur with @snapshoe, it isn't true, that the exception object has to be casted to a string before printing; you have this in the _print_ function documentation: **"All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like `str()` does"**. I can only assume, so please bear with me, but you might have done a concatenation like `print('Error is: ' + str(e))` when the cast is indeed required, but that is because of the concatenation and not the _print_ function.

Comment: @Paul P below has actually mentioned the right way for this string casting, use `e.args[0]` to get the stringified message

Answer (score 13):

Another way of accessing the message is via `args`:

```py
try:
    ...
except ValueError as e:
    print(e.args[0])
```

Answer (score 10):

Python 3 requires casting the exception to string before printing:

```py
try:
    ...
except ValueError as error:
    print(str(error))
```

Comment: This is still not true. `print(error)` works just fine in that context in Python 3.

Comment: @snapshoe If this is not true, why does it get upvoted? Perhaps there are cases where it is really needed? I doubt it, but who knows

Comment: @questionto42 using previous concating of strings causes this to be needed : ie:

`print("Error: " + e)`

would fail if you do not cast the string. Using proper formatting:

`print(f"Error: {e}")`

works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `logging`

```
import logging
try:
    int("dog")
except Exception as e:
    logging.warning(e)
    logging.error(e)
```

gives

```
WARNING:root:invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'dog'
ERROR:root:invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'dog'

[Program finished]
```

Just typing the exception gives,

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'dog'

[Program finished]
```

Depends on how you want to process the output