# "print" an oracle query in django

Tags: html, django, oracle

I'm trying to print the result of a query in a HTML page on django. I have everything set but I don't know what to put in the HTML file to print the query. **For example**, my view is

[image]

Comment: Don't share an image of the code, please share the actual code as text

Comment: this might help you
 [query result in html](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40606228/6880611)

Answer (score 0):

In your template page 'projeto_cartao_app/codigo.html' call the variable by

```
{% if record %}
{{record}} 
{% endif %}
```

The values are then passed and printed on your HTML page.

Comment: it gives me an error: ValueError at /projeto_cartao_app
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 13; 2 is required
It's because of the {'record:record'} ?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097461/python-valueerror-error-message. Include exception handling to your code.

Comment: it returns a blank page with only this "<cx_Oracle.Cursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to portcli@172.22.20.197/dbpt>> "